# coredata metaData fetch error

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

In my IOS app, in statement

```
 NSDictionary *x = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 
     metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
     URL:<url> error:&error];
```

I am getting following error and x is nil:

> "SQLite error code:3850, 'not an error' errno:9"

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be

```
#define SQLITE_INTERRUPT    9   /* Operation terminated by sqlite3_interrupt()*/
```

([Source](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html))

Comment: why am i getting this error, is there a way to get around this error?

Comment: I guess your database is accessed by some other process before this one is finished. One way is to *lock* the database before and after this call. Another one is to do this call on one particular thread (making sure there are no other threads accessing the database) and just wait until it completes.

Comment: I just tried this without any error. (Returns `null` in my case, BTW.)